# In IOS, how can I change the source of an image by using setNativeProps in react native

Tags: ios, image, react-native

I am developing UI in react native, and I'm trying to change the `<Image>`'s source by using setNativeProps.

My code works fine in android :

```
this._imageReference.setNativeProps({ src: [{uri: "http://myImage.jpg"}] });
```

In IOS, syntax seems to be :

```
this._imageReference.setNativeProps({ source: [{uri: "http://myImage.jpg"}] });
```

But it doesn't work in my case.

Do you have any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: Related to React Native issue https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29234